# How do I write files that gzip well?

Tags: compression, gzip

I'm working on a web project, and I need to create a format to transmit files very efficiently (lots of data).  The data is entirely numerical, and split into a few sections.  Of course, this will be transferred with gzip compression.

I can't seem to find any information on what makes a file compress better than another file.

How can I encode floats (32bit) and short integers (16bit) in a format that results in the smallest gzip size?

P.s. it will be a lot of data, so saving 5% means a lot here.  There won't likely be any repeats in the floats, but the integers will likely repeat about 5-10 times in each file.

Comment: does it have to be gzip? will you consider other compression format?

Comment: @mvp, no it must be gzip due to server/browser architecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to compress data is to remove redundancy. This is essentially what any compression tool does - it looks for redundant/repeatable parts and replaces them with link/reference to the same data that was observed before in your stream.

If you want to make your data format more efficient, you should remove everything that could be possibly removed. For example, it is more efficient to store numbers in binary rather than in text (JSON, XML, etc). If you have to use text format, consider removing unnecessary spaces or linefeeds.

One good example of efficient binary format is [google protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/). It has lots of benefits, and not least of them is storing numbers as variable number of bytes (i.e. number 1 consumes less space than number 1000000).

Text or binary, but if you can sort your data before sending, it can increase possibility for gzip compressor to find redundant parts, and most likely to increase compression ratio.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on protocol buffers!  If I can work that into the current flow it seems like a really good option.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said 32-bit floats and 16-bit integers, you are already coding them in binary.

Consider the range and useful accuracy of your numbers.  If you can limit those, you can recode the numbers using fewer bits.  Especially the floats, which may have more bits than you need.

If the right number of bits is not a multiple of eight, then treat your stream of bytes as a stream of bits and use only the bits needed.  Be careful to deal with the end of your data properly so that the added bits to go to the next byte boundary are not interpreted as another number.

If your numbers have some correlation to each other, then you should take advantage of that.  For example, if the difference between successive numbers is usually small, which is the case for a representation of a waveform for example, then send the differences instead of the numbers.  Differences can be coded using variable-length integers or Huffman coding or a combination, e.g. Huffman codes for ranges and extra bits within each range.

If there are other correlations that you can use, then design a predictor for the next value based on the previous values.  Then send the difference between the actual and predicted value.  In the previous example, the predictor is simply the last value.  An example of a more complex predictor is a 2D predictor for when the numbers represent a 2D table and both adjacent rows and columns are correlated.  The PNG image format has a few examples of 2D predictors.

All of this will require experimentation with your data, ideally large amounts of your data, to see what helps and what doesn't or has only marginal benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Use binary instead of text.

A float in its text representation with 8 digits (a float has a precision of eight decimal digits), plus decimal separator, plus field  separator, consumes 10 bytes. In binary representation, it takes only 4.

If you need to use text, use hex. It consumes less digits.

But although this makes a lot of difference for the uncompressed file, these differences might disappear after compression, since the compression algo should implicitly take care if that. But you may try.